# Where is VP9 Codec's support for Depth Channel?

Tags: depth, libvpx

According to Wikipedia's VP9 entry and Google's Discussion Board, VP9 supports both alpha  and depth channels.
but i scanned the source code of libvpx several times. There is no doubt the alpha channel is there. But the only times the word "depth" mentioned in the source files are about the depths of AVL tree or Marcoblock lookheads.
Does the released VP9 Video Codec really support Depth Channel?
Can someone point it out for me where to look among the source files the lines of code describing the depth channel are? ...one line of proof is enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depth channel is not supported right now. Alpha channel support is still under development (CONFIG_ALPHA) and is not supported in the current codec profile.